# Non-Linear animation getting distortion issues

Tags: animation, rigging, .fbx

A first time blender user here struggling with an NLA issue.  I have imported a t-posed character (fbx) using mixamo, and have also downloaded a few animations (non-skinned). The character seems to load in fine, in a T-Pose.  When I am in the Non-linear animation editor, when I add the imported FBX of a walk cycle, my character has rotated 90 degrees, and the hands now move inside the body of the character.  Being new to blender, I very well could have missed some settings or not know of a feature in Blender.  In edit mode, my character is no longer in T-Pose, and has rotated 90 degrees, but from what I have read, that can't be changed?  I have attached a photo of what is going on, and if there is any other info I can supply, please let me know.  Thank you!  [image: Distortion upon applying animation]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? upload and share the URL it will create https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Moonboots, thank you for the response, and here is the file, with the issue: https://pasteall.org/blend/2d785bc8d9004844997ed6be91838c71

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, as you say, the armature you've assigned to your character is no longer in T pose, its new pose (with arms down) make the *Walking* action mess up the bones because of their new orientations.

To fix that, you can duplicate the *Armature* modifier (in the modifier, down arrow button > *Duplicate*), in *Pose* mode, reset all the bones (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) and move the arm bones so that they are in T pose (don't pay attention to the mesh deformations), select the character and apply the second modifier (select the modifier and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode again and go in the header menu > *Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose*:

[image]

As for the 90° on the Z axis, as there are no keyframes assigned to the armature object itself, you can simply rotate it 90°.

Also don't forget to center the armature's origin.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will give it a try.  Again, I am very new to blender, so I have a few questions on your answer.  In Object and Pose Mode, my character looks correct with the T-Pose, but when I select Edit Mode, that is where he rotates 90 degrees, and his arms move down.  I assume Edit mode is where I need to fix things to match with object and pose mode?  In Edit mode, is there a way to have the armature be in the correct pose, and then align the mesh to it, similar to your image?  Thank you for you help so far.

Comment: I can't see it rotation 90° as you say so I'm not sure what's happening. For the pose, please read my edit and tell me if it's clear

Comment: Okay I will give this a try.  My armature is from mixamo, and I am only hours into blender, so I will need to find where armature modifiers are, and follow your steps.  I will keep you updated.  Thank you again.

Comment: In my opinion it's a bit too ambitious to try that with only few hours of Blender   ;)

Comment: when you say move the arms, after resetting the bones in pose mode, are you meaning the mesh itself?

Comment: no with the solution I give you don't need to move the mesh, move the arm bones in Pose mode

Comment: I appreciate all of your information.  I am still working through it, but I think I will do better when I get more comfortable in blender.  I spend most of my time in Maya, so it is a challenge to find things in Blender at this point.  In the meantime, I loaded in another character.  It is the same position in object, edit, and pose mode, thus confirming the issue was with the characters position, and is encouragement for better planning in future works using blender.  Thank you very much for all of your time and help in resolving this issue!

Comment: you're welcome!